# Why `std::mem::forget` cannot be used for creating static references?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
pub trait Forget {
    fn forget_me_as_ptr(self) -> *const Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        let p = addr_of!(self);
        forget(self);
        p
    }

    fn forget_me_as_mut_ptr(self) -> *mut Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        self.forget_me_as_ptr() as *mut Self
    }

    fn forget_me_as_ref(self) -> &'static Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        self.forget_me_as_mut_ref()
    }

    fn forget_me_as_mut_ref(mut self) -> &'static mut Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        let p = addr_of_mut!(self);
        forget(self);
        unsafe { p.as_mut().unwrap() }
    }
}

pub fn default<T: Forget + Default>() -> &'static T {
    T::default().forget_me_as_ref()
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Player {
    health: u8,
    name: String,
    aliases: Vec<String>,
}

impl Drop for Player {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping [{}, {self:p}]", type_name::<Self>());
    }
}

impl Display for Player {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "[{}, {self:p}] = name: {}, health: {}, aliases: {:#?}",
            type_name::<Self>(),
            self.name,
            self.health,
            self.aliases
        )
    }
}

impl Forget for Player {}

impl Default for Player {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            health: 100,
            name: "default".into(),
            aliases: vec!["default".to_string()],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p = default::<Player>();
    println!("{p}");
}
```

output:

```
$ cargo r
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/static_factory`
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

In the above code snippet why is it segfaulting ?
`std::mem::forget` just takes ownership and does not run the destructor/drop which can exactly be used to create references whose lifetime is static ? Where is the flaw in this logic ? Am new to rust and kind of wanted to understand what is the relation between references, instances of struct T, pointers. The code above looks logically correct from a naive thought. Please explain and correct.

Comment: If I understand correctly: The value still lives on the stack, and so in your `default` function, you create a reference to a position on the stack. When your function returns, the stack pointer is reset, meaning that your reference now points to an area that is now invalid to access, as that stack space should be free

Comment: yep. just realized this now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76706843/17878829

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `std::mem::forget` avoids running the `Drop` implementation but since `self` is a local variable, the memory for it will still be reclaimed and used for other things.

To get the desired behavior, you would need to move it to a stable address that won't be reused. You can do this by putting it in a `Box`, getting the pointer to it, and forgetting the box. Fortunately there is already a function for that: [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak). Something like:

```
pub trait Forget {
    // ... the rest ...

    fn forget_me_as_mut_ref(mut self) -> &'static mut Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Box::leak(Box::new(self))
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Local variables, like the parameters of a function live on the stack, whether `drop` is called on it's memory doesn't make a difference in that any pointer to it becomes dangling as soon as you leave the function. Therefore `unsafe { p.as_mut().unwrap() }` is unsound when `p` points to local memory (such as the argument `self`) and you return the result.

Comment: exactly my thought: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76706843/17878829

Answer (score 0):

My suspect is with the line:

```
pub fn default<T: Forget + Default>() -> &'static T {
    T::default().forget_me_as_ref()
}
```

`T::default()` creates a temporary object on stack for which we create a reference. Once the function call ends the memory corresponding to the stack allocated object is lets say garbled. Had the object been created on heap i think this would go away.

Comment: Actually `default` is sound iff `forget_me_as_ref` is because `self` is moved into the method.